# Send 2 ETH from Nano to Bittrex, but run out of gas

Tags: transactions, ether, gas, out-of-gas, pending-transactions

I sent 2 ETH from my Nano wallet to Bittrex exchange. However, the transaction gets stucked due to lack of gas. I expect to see my 2 ETH goes back to my wallet minus the gas fee. However, I haven't seen the 2 ETH balance in my wallet. How can I recover my 2 ETH. Greatly appreciated for any help.

[Etherscan Tx details](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf494e84b52c962ad027d14bd17182498e2f1f404).

Comment: did you get it sorted?

Answer (score 1):

As you have correctly mentioned this an `out of gas` error. What happens in this situation is, it returns with failure and rolls back to the state it was before sending the transaction except that you have to pay the gas cost to the miner for executing it.

When I inspected your account the balance is <kbd>213.119202218 Ether</kbd>

[image]

To check the correctness of the balance it's needed to add all the INs and deduct **succesfully completed OUTs** **(except the failed one)** and deduct all the Tx costs of OUTs as below (assuming no internal transactions happened),

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| IN Txs                  | OUT Txs (Except fails) | Fees for OUT Txs      | Balance     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 15.42115568 + 100 + 100 | - 2.3                  |-(0.001512462+0.000441)|213.119202218|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**i.e. 15.42115568 + 100 + 100 - 2.3 - 0.001512462 - 0.000441 = 213.119202218**

which is exactly your account balance. So your ETH balance in wallet is correct and you have the 2ETH remaining.

> I expect to see my 2 ETH goes back to my wallet minus the gas fee

If what you meant by this is to see a reverse transaction kind of thing to happen and a see a `IN` transaction again, that's not the case. There's no need of such thing because actually an amount of 2 ETH was not sent and it's in your wallet already.